# How to manipulate collection without hitting the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In my Rails application I have this little helper method that takes a collection as a parameter:

```
def calculate_column_width(collection)
  if collection.where(:sample => true).present?
    "10%"
  else
    "20%"
  end
end
```

It works but I don't like the fact that it creates two additional database queries.

How can I rewrite the function so it runs on the collection (e.g. `@people`) which has already been loaded into memory by Rails?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd be best served by not using an ActiveRecord method and instead treating the collection like an array. To your example above:

```
def calculate_column_width(collection)
  if collection.find { |object| object.sample == true }
    "10%"
  else
    "20%"
  end
end
```

Note that this `find` method is the one that exists on ruby arrays and will just return the first thing that matches the condition. It should avoid doing additional database queries.